# Is the R-process the only mechanism for making heavy elements in a neutron star merger?

Tags: nuclear-physics, neutron-stars

Is it possible that in the debris field left over from a neutron star merger (kilonova) there are heavy element sized chuncks of (mostly) neutron matter that undergo rapid beta-decay to become the heavy elements observed?  I seem to remember reading about this possibility shortly after the recent LIGO observation, but now everything I see only mentions the R-process. The R-process was a logical explanation for the heavy elements when it was thought they resulted only from supernova events, but is there now a wider range of possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume by "neutron matter" you mean the major component (by mass) of a neutron star - a fluid comprised mainly of neutrons with a small component of protons and electrons in "beta equilibrium".

If so, then this cannot decay into r-process elements like gold and osmium. All it can do is decay into a plasma of protons and electrons.

To build heavy, neutron-rich elements requires the rapid capture of neutrons (the r-process) onto already heavy elements. Such elements exist in the crusts of merging neutron stars. After the rapid neutron capture, the unstable products *do* undergo beta decay to become the stable "r-process elements".